# connect to remote desktop with same session

Tags: remote-desktop

I connect to a red-hat server using a window remote desktop. When I disconnected and re-connect again, the red-hat server gives me a new desktop (the web-browser are still running in the red-hat server but I cannot see it in the new desktop). How can I login to the red-hat server continuing the same session and seeing the same desktop? Thank you!

Update: I found a [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133343/how-do-i-set-up-xrdp-session-that-reuses-an-existing-sessionediting) /ect/xrdp/xrdp.ini which needs root access. Is it possible to configure xrdp so that each user can reuse their own session if such session already exists?

redhat remote-desktop